# Accordion content left alignment renders causing indention issue - css, html

Tags: html, css, accordion, indentation

I am using a combination of tabs and accordion panels to organizes a text document and functionally everything works but I am having trouble with formatting it like a word document specifically with the white space indentions. I have been using lists to add white space but the text within each accordion block seems to be completely left aligned and ignores the list formatting. Any idea what could be causing it? Thanks!

Code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dyjwi/

I think there may be something somewhere in this section of the css causing it, it may have something to do with the display or padding.

```
/*Define Accordion box*/
.accordion { 
    width:880px; 
    margin:10px auto; 
    color:#000000; 
    background:#000000; 
    padding:0px; 
}

/*General Accordion****************************************************************************/
/*Set style of open slide*/
.accordion section:target { 
    background:#FFF; 
    padding:10px;
}
.accordion section:target:hover { 
    background:#FFF; 
}
.accordion section:target h2 {
    width:100%;
}
.accordion section:target h2 a{ 
    color:#333; 
    padding:0;
}
.accordion section:target p {
    display:block;
}
.accordion section h2 a{
    padding:8px 10px;
    display:block; 
    font-size:16px; 
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#eee; 
    text-decoration:none; 
}

/*set style of closed slide*/
.accordion section{ 
    float:left; 
    color:#333; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    background: #333; 
    margin:3px; 
}
.accordion section:hover {
    background:#444;
}
.accordion section p { 
    display:none; 
}
.accordion section:after{
    position:relative;
    font-size:24px;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;}
.accordion section:nth-child(1):after{content:'1';}
.accordion section:nth-child(2):after{content:'2';}
.accordion section:nth-child(3):after{content:'3';}
.accordion section:nth-child(4):after{content:'4';}
.accordion section:nth-child(5):after{content:'5';}
.accordion section:nth-child(6):after{content:'6'; }
.accordion section:nth-child(7):after{content:'7';}
.accordion section:nth-child(8):after{content:'8';}
.accordion section:nth-child(9):after{content:'9';}
.accordion section:nth-child(10):after{content:'10';}
.accordion section:nth-child(11):after{content:'11';}
.accordion section:nth-child(12):after{content:'12';}
/*End General Accordion****************************************************************************/

/*Vertical Accordion *************************************************************************/
.vertical section{ width:100%; height:40px;
    -webkit-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
}
/*Set height of the slide*/
.vertical :target{ 
    height:250px; 
    width:97%; 
}

.vertical section h2 {
    position:relative; 
    left:0; 
    top:0px; 
}

/*Set position of the number on the slide*/
.vertical section:after{ 
    top:-60px;
    left:810px;
}
.vertical section:target:after{ 
    left:-9999px;
}
/*Vertical Accordion****************************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm you are using a reset :

```
 * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

So add this to your code CSS:

```
ul li ul li{
    margin:inherit; /* or some size in px */
}
```

and change your html like this :

```
<ul>
    <li><b>Tips:</b>
    <ul>
        <li>- Apply to object with: Modify >> Make Live</li>
        <li>- Creating a circle plane: Create circle curve -> convert to plane</li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/core972/X2Lzw/) on jsfiddle, I have some problem with codepen.